# Fillomino: Number Attack!

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

This is my first time making a Fillomino. Hope you enjoy!

> Fillomino (taken from Nikoli):
>
> - Fill in all empty cells with numbers under the following rules.
> - Divide all of the board into blocks.
> - Fill each block with the same number horizontally or vertically.
> - Each block contains as many cells as the number in the block.
> - Same sized blocks cannot touch each other, horizontally or vertically.

[image]

And [here](https://puzz.link/p?fillomino/10/10/2h2c2g3g35g5i3id5ch1g12hd1h2i2h2i2g9j2i1g6k19i6h2d2h2i1329992g6n6) is a handy puzz.link for your solving convinience.

(Accepted answer contains complete explanation of answer.)

Comment: This has multiple solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand Lukas Rotter's comment into an answer,

We can get this far by logical deduction ("escape" to make room for a polyomino, draw walls to prevent two polyominoes of the same type from touching, fill all room left, etc.):

[image: logical end]

However, the 6 and 13 can fill the remaining squares near them either way. Also, the empty 3-area on the bottom row can be 1/2/2 or 3/3/3. This has no unique solution. (There are in fact exactly 4 solutions)

Comment: Nooooo, so close to a unique solution! I guess you get a checkmark for explaining why it has multiple solutions, but still, I worked so hard on this, explaining my not-so-activeness lately. Is there like a website that chekcs if your puzzles have multiple solutions or something? And, sorry for the failed puzzle :(

Comment: Test-solving, especially if you can get another person to test-solve, is the best way to make sure your puzzle 1) has a unique solution and 2) is at the appropriate difficulty level

Comment: @Anonymus25-ReinstateMonica You should solve them with **pure logic**. Don't make *any* marks that you are not 100% sure of - only write something down when you are unsure of all other options. (This is the intended method for [grid-deduction] puzzles in general, but it's especially important for uniqueness checking.)